# Async and Await not working with Axios React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, axios, asynchronous-javascript

I am trying to test my react project locally with my computer and with my phone. I am using JavaScript not TypeScript.
When I run the project on my computer everything works fine, but when I try to load it on my phone, I get an error: `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): undefined is not an object (evaluating 'scheduleArr.forEach')`. I thought I was using `async` and `await` correctly because this code workes on my computer. I'm confused as to why this code works on one platform but not the other.

```
async function getSchedule() {
  let scheduleArr = await axios.get('api/schedule/')
    .then(response => { 
      return response.data; 
     })
    .catch((error) => {
       console.log(`ERROR: ${error}`);
    });

  scheduleArr.forEach(game => {
    /* do stuff */
  }

});
```

I think this problem is directly related to `async` and `await` because when I comment out this function, my project loads correctly on my phone.

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: when using `async` and `await` you need `try` and `catch` blocks and not `then` and `catch` methods

Comment: Is your phone on the same network as your computer? Or are you using your mobile data network?

Comment: @codemonkey my phone is on the same network. When I tested the style of my app without any logic, it rendered correctly.

Comment: @Sysix Can you explain this a little bit more? When I change my `.then` `.catch` to `try` `catch` I get an error on both devices.

Comment: The point is that your `axios` request obviously bombs on your phone and the `try` `catch` thing will help identify the specific error.

Comment: @codemonkey I am running my react client on `localhost:3000`and I am running my backend on `localhost:5000`. Could the issue be that on mobile, my client isn't able to access the backend?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `async/await` pattern with `then`. Either use it like :

```
async function getSchedule() {
    try {
      let scheduleArr = await axios.get("api/schedule/");
      console.log(scheduleArr.data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`ERROR: ${err}`);
    }

    scheduleArr.forEach(game => {
      /* do stuff */
    });
  }
```

Or with the default pattern :

```
function getSchedule() {
    axios
      .get("api/schedule/")
      .then(response => {
        let scheduleArr = response.data;

        // Do this inside the 'then'
        scheduleArr.forEach(game => {
          /* do stuff */
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(`ERROR: ${error}`);
      });
  }
```

Note that I moved your `foreach` loop into the `then`. It is asynchronous and therefore need to be triggered only when you get the result of your api call.

Comment: This didn't solve my problem, but I think this is better coding practice

Comment: @Chase This answer is not meant to actually solve your problem. It will simply help troubleshoot the origins of it.

Comment: @Chase **undefined is not an object (evaluating 'scheduleArr.forEach')** You get this error because you are trying to loop over `schedulArr` when it is not initialized. As I said, you need to put it inside your `then`. Now, if it still does not works, share more of your code so we can check it out please.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue was. It had nothing to do with `async` `await` or `axios`.

This was my code before

```
function getSchedule() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/api/schedule/")
      .then(response => {
        let scheduleArr = response.data;

        // Do this inside the 'then'
        scheduleArr.forEach(game => {
          /* do stuff */
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(`ERROR: ${error}`);
      });
  }
```

I changed my API call to use my actual local IP instead of localhost

```
function getSchedule() {
    axios
      .get("http://192.168.X.XX:5000/api/schedule/")
      .then(response => {
        let scheduleArr = response.data;

        // Do this inside the 'then'
        scheduleArr.forEach(game => {
          /* do stuff */
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(`ERROR: ${error}`);
      });
  }
```

Nesting my code in the `.then` block did fix my `undefined` error even with the bad url. Thank you for that suggestion @Quentin Grisel.

Fixing my url let me test it on different devices.